# Submit form depending on ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have created a form. On the submission of the form i make an ajax request which tells me whether the data is valid or not. What i want to do is that if the ajax response tells that the data is valid then it should submit the form but if data is not valid then it should not submit the form.

```
$('#agentLogin').submit(function(ev){
       ev.preventDefault();
       var username=$('#agentEmail').val();
       var password=$('#agentPassword').val();
       $.ajax({
           url: '<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('site/agentLogin'); ?>',
           type: 'POST',
           data: {
               email: username,
               pwd: password
           },
           success: function(data){
               if(data === 'invalid'){
                   $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Invalid Username and password');
               }else if(data === 'deactivated'){
                   $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Account is deactivated');
               }else if(data === 'valid'){
                   // submit form here
               }
           }
       });
    });
```

**Problem:-** When the data is not valid It does not submit the form. but if the data is valid then also it does not submits the form. How can i resolve this issue?

**Already tried:-**

```
$(this).submit();
return true;
```

Comment: `url: '<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('site/agentLogin'); ?>',` is this correct? checkout the quotes.

Comment: @jai yes it is correct. I am getting the ajax response very well

Comment: Try using the native [`this.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit) to continue submitting rather than jQuery's [`$(this).submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: @JonathanLonowski not working sir

Comment: @Letmesee Save a reference to the `<form>` in the `.submit(function)` -- `var form = this;`. Then, use the native submit -- `form.submit()`. `this` inside `$.ajax()` callbacks won't be the `<form>`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Why did you delete your answer? It was correct and proper way to go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
$('#agentLogin').submit(function (ev, submit) {

    if (!submit) {

        ev.preventDefault();

        var username = $('#agentEmail').val(),
            password = $('#agentPassword').val(),
            $form = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'url',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: username,
                pwd: password
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data === 'invalid') {
                    $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Invalid Username and password');
                }
                else if (data === 'deactivated') {
                    $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Account is deactivated');
                }
                else if (data === 'valid') {
                    $form.trigger('submit', [true]);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

The reason it didn't work with your original code is that when you try to call `$(this).submit()` it triggers the same event handler which attempts to validate with AJAX request all over again and never actually submit a form. To fix it you need to tell event handler somehow that when you submit a form manually you don't want to run validation anymore.  I am passing additional parameter for this:

```
$form.trigger('submit', [true]);
```

Comment: What about the variable `if (!submit) ` used here? where it set?

Comment: @MuraliMurugesan `$form.trigger('submit', [true]);`. Second parameter of `trigger`.

Comment: Thank you sir. It solved my problem and took me out of lots of frustrations. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can continue submission of a `<form>` with the [native `.submit()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit), which should [only start the default action](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-form-submit) that was previously prevented [without rerunning event bindings](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-form-submit).

> The `submit()` method, when invoked, must [submit](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-form-submit) the `form` element from the `form` element itself, with the *submitted from `submit()` method* flag set.

> 5) If the *submitted from `submit()` method* flag is not set, then [fire a simple event](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#fire-a-simple-event) that bubbles and is cancelable named `submit`, at *`form`*. [...]

Though, you'll also need to store a reference to the `<form>` as `this` can and will often be different between `function`s, including embedded callbacks.

```
$('#agentLogin').submit(function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
   var form = this; // store reference as `this` can change between `function`s
   var username=$('#agentEmail').val();
   var password=$('#agentPassword').val();
   $.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('site/agentLogin'); ?>',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
           email: username,
           pwd: password
       },
       success: function(data){
           if(data === 'invalid'){
               $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Invalid Username and password');
           }else if(data === 'deactivated'){
               $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Account is deactivated');
           }else if(data === 'valid'){
               form.submit(); // use native method to counter `preventDefault()`
           }
       }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#agentLogin').submit(function(ev){
   var myForm=$(this);
   if(myForm.data("action")=="submit"){
    return true;
   }
   ev.preventDefault();
   var username=$('#agentEmail').val();
   var password=$('#agentPassword').val();
    $.ajax({
       url: '<?php echo $this->createAbsoluteUrl('site/agentLogin'); ?>',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
           email: username,
           pwd: password
       },
    success: function(data){
           if(data === 'invalid'){
               $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Invalid Username and password');
               return false;
           }else if(data === 'deactivated'){
               $('#agentLoginStatus').html('Account is deactivated');
           }else if(data === 'valid'){
               myForm.data("action","submit");
               myForm.submit();
           }
       }

 });
```

Comment: @Letmesee, i have added some flag and based on it you need to submit. CHeck updated answer

Comment: it submitted the form but its also submitting when the data is not valid

Comment: @Letmesee, added `return false`  in invalid condition

Answer (score 0):

Here we can use submithandler of the ajax. The reason is that the submithandler works with submit button and validates the data too..