# Is it ok to initiate an ajax call after form submission ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

An ajax post request will be issued after  form submission.

I  want to call the ajax post after submission of the form.

But ajax call is issued before form submission, should I need to delay the ajax call? how to do that after form submission?

**by submitting form I'm calling an add function to save data**

```
$("#section-form").submit(function (e) {


    save_class_info();

});

function save_class_info() {

   var  action = 'saveclassinfo';


    var campus_info = {
        'campus_name': campus_name,
        'shift_name': shift_name,
        'medium_name': medium_name,
        'class_name': class_id,
        'teacher_id': teacher_id,
        'edit': 'false'
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "/" + root + "/" + controller + "/" + action,
        type: "post",
        data: campus_info,
        success: function (response) {

            console.log('done');
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });
}
```

Comment: after form submit page will reload.so you should run ajax first.on success or error you should submit form

Comment: I need to save data before ajax call cause i will use that data during ajax post call :( @FastSnail

Comment: if so send two ajax request

Comment: @Amran there is only one ajax call in your code and that is your form submission right?

Comment: $("#section-form").submit(function (e) {e.preventDefault();  save_class_info(); }); please try this .

Comment: nope .By submitting form um saving some data  and by ajax call um saving different data to another table.I need to set a delay between form  submission and ajax call. after submission of form ajax call will be issued @The_ehT

Comment: @Amran you have another form ?right.can you show it.i see people get confused

Comment: @Amran when you use default `action` property to submit form data the page reloads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Submit form depending on ajax response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558826/submit-form-depending-on-ajax-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my mistake.During  form submission I can't issue an ajax call because that page will be refreshed after submitting the form. So I've done the submission of the form through another ajax call and after that call, I've issued another ajax post cause I need the data from success of  1st ajax call.

Thanks all for letting  me know the problem of my approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable default form submission behaviors by using  [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```
$("#section-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    save_class_info();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to prevent form submit.

```
$("#section-form").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    save_class_info();
});
```

Comment: i want ajax call will be issued after submission of form. You are preventing that !

Comment: If you don't prevent form submission, the page will reload, and all data won't  stay. There is no reason to use Ajax.